# Postfix is not rejecting recipients addresses when mailx is used

Tags: postfix, filter, mailx

I have a problem with postfix to reject outgoing email for some address in blacklist.

This is my configure `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
      check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit
```

File `/etc/postfix/bad_recipients`:

```
phongdang@chotot.vn REJECT
```

Then I use command:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/bad_recipients
```

to create bad_recipients.db

and restart postfix: `/etc/init.d/postfix restart`

Then I try send mail to phongdang@chotot.vn:

```
echo "hello world" | mailx -s "Test from CLI" phongdang@chotot.vn
```

Maillog:

```
Nov  4 19:54:50 cent6 postfix/pickup[32452]: 851B011FD2B: uid=0 from=<root>
Nov  4 19:54:50 cent6 postfix/cleanup[32491]: 851B011FD2B: message-id=<20141104125450.851B011FD2B@cent6.5-template>
Nov  4 19:54:50 cent6 postfix/qmgr[32453]: 851B011FD2B: from=<root@cent6.5-template>, size=447, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  4 19:54:50 cent6 postfix/smtp[32493]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[2607:f8b0:400e:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Nov  4 19:54:51 cent6 postfix/smtp[32493]: 851B011FD2B: to=<phongdang@chotot.vn>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.28.26]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.05/0/0.6/0.51, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1415105691 x3si145045pdr.187 - gsmtp)
Nov  4 19:54:51 cent6 postfix/qmgr[32453]: 851B011FD2B: removed
```

And I receive email although I restricted email phongdang@chotot.vn. Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- It is because `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` only apply to the mails received by `smtpd` daemon through an SMTP transaction.
- The mails submitted using `sendmail` or `mailx` command is queued in `maildrop` queue by `postdrop` command, which is picked up by `pickup` and fed to cleanup directly.

You can't restrict recipients for the mails submitted through `sendmail` or `mailx` commands.

The only solution to this problem is force your applications to send mail only through smtp.

Answer (score 4):

As [clement](https://serverfault.com/users/184188/clement) said, your restriction doesn't work because the email was queued via `pickup`.

As workaround you can apply a solution from [postfix-users mailing-list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/177345)

In `master.cf` look the `pickup` entry. Then add `-o content_filter=smtp:[127.0.0.1]:12525`

```
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
    -o content_filter=smtp:[127.0.0.1]:12525
```

Then add another smtpd process (port 12525) also in `master.cf` to perform rejection

```
127.0.0.1:12525 inet    n       -       n       -       25      smtpd
```

Don't forget to restart postfix

**The caveats from the [same page](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/177345)**: This overrides the default delivery agent for locally submitted email, but adds to the already I/O overhead of local submission.